# How to check if Easy Digital Downloads customer has purchased product?

Tags: wordpress

How to check if Easy Digital Downloads customer has purchased product?

Hello, my English is not good, but I hope that a good solution will be found for the problem that has arisen for me.

Please help me to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://easydigitaldownloads.com/docs/edd_has_user_purchased/

```
<?php if( edd_has_user_purchased(get_user_by('email', get_comment_author_email())->ID, get_the_ID()) ) : ?>

    <span class="edd-purchased">purchaser</span>

<?php endif; ?>
```